# execute cli git command in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am trying to run *git* in **AWS Lambda** to checkout a repository.

- I am using *nodejs*
- I am not using *nodegit* because I want to use a personal git server

How can I execute a *CLI* command in *NodeJS* on **AWS Lambda**? For example, execute `git log`.

I tried the following to install the *git* command:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const message = event.message;
    const child = exec('yum -y install git' + message, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
    });
};
```

But I received this error:

> Could not set cachedir: [Errno 30] Read-only file system:
>   '/var/tmp/yum-  sbx_user1073-kH3W9q' You need to be root to perform
>   this command.

Comment: You can easily run bash command from nodejs but it's hard to install git on lambda.